# Check if asynctask with Progress Dialog is finished in non activity class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a created non activity java class for doing same calculation from different activities. This class has asynctask with progress Dialog in it. In most cases calculation is not the last operation of activity and everything goes fine, but when it is my Progress Dialog goes lost.

Example:

```
myJavaClass doCalculations= new myJavaClass (SomeActivity.this);

doCalculations.Do(); //<------ method Do has asysctask with Progress Dialog

finish();
```

result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2bbf820e V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,483} not attached to window manager
```

How can I wait for asynctask to finish and then finish activity?

---

Additional question: Is using asynctask in non activity class is a bad practice ?

Comment: Google recommend to avoid using ProgressDialog. You have to deal with activity state loss and configuration change event. Instead use DialogFragment.  Checkout this example http://javatechig.com/?p=8808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your activity active until the `AsyncTask` has finished its job, you can define a callback method in the activity that gets called when the task has finished and can react appropriately:

In the `Activity`:

```
private boolean finishAfterCurrentTask = false;

public void onTaskFinished() {
    if (finishAfterCurrentTask) { // set this to true when running the last task
        finish();
    }
}
```

In the `AsyncTask`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    activity.onTaskFinished();
}
```

I'm assuming that you're keeping a reference to the activity in `myJavaClass`. In case that you're calling the `AsyncTask` from a non-UI thread, you should probably run the callback (and also all methods involving the dialog) via [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

As for the second question - if you use an `AsyncTask` in a class which methods can be called from a thread other than the UI thread, it's necessary to use `runOnUiThread()` to perform any operations on the UI, such as changing the contents of a view or showing/hiding a dialog, beause `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are called from the same thread as `execute()`.

On the other hand, if you start the task inside one of the UI callbacks, which are guaranteed to run on the UI thread, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: I am passing activity context via activity.this. How to write reference to activity?

Comment: You can define a filed `private Activity activity` and save it in the constructor: `myJavaClass(Activity activity) { this.activity = activity }`. You cat then use this reference as a `Context` for methods that require it. It has its drawbacks, though, because in an event of a configuration change (such as screen rotation), the Activity will be destroyed and recreated, rendering the reference invalid. In this case you should update it, so it points to the newly created activity.

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask has a `onPostExecute` method you can finish the activity from there

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        finish(); // you'll probably have to call finish() with a callback function
}
```

The `onPostExecute` method is called when the `doInBackground` method is finished, on that method you can finish the activity and close the progressdialog

Comment: In most cases Asynctask is not last operation of activity, so I can't use this

Comment: just send a parameter that indicated whether to finish the activity or not when done

Comment: finish() method is not recognized in myJavaClass.

Comment: Then add an Activity parameter to the Do() function. You can use  (SomeActivity.this) value for it.

Comment: 'protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            if (finishActivity==true){

                finish();

            }

        }'

//finish();  not recognized command

Comment: Send the activities context to the AsyncTask and then call finish on that context